# How to dynamically the label number

Tags: vb.net, oledbcommand

This is a tennis tournament simulation program I'm Trying to make a tree. Everything its working perfectly but I have a big problem. I can't progress to the next stage with the winners of the firts games. Because I can't change the "target" label where I want to write the winners name. Here's a print:[image]

This is how I Generate the winners who is going to the next stage and it actually works.~

```
Public Sub Gerar_Vencedor(Atleta1, Atleta2)
    Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                               "Data Source = E:\dev\Ganso\BaseDados_ClubeTenis.accdb"
        con.Close()
        con.Open()
        Dim busca = "Select Vencedor From Jogo Where idAtleta1 = '" & Atleta1 & "' and idAtleta2 = '" & Atleta2 & "'"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(busca, con)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        ' A variável sql vai receber a string para fazer o select a base de dados
        'Try
        ' é aberta ligação a Bdados
        ' declaração de um comando que vai executar a instrução sql na base de dados
        ' variável que vai receber os registos resultantes da instrução sql
        ' ciclo que vai percorrer todos os registos do comando anterior
        While dr.Read()
            Label9.Text = dr("Vencedor")
        End While
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

My problem is that `Label9.Text = dr("Vencedor")` because everytime I get a winner it goes to label9.
My final question is: Is there anyway to dynamically change the label without repeating this function over and over.

Thanks.

Comment: You could pass in a label or make the method smarter to get multiple items and populate them from the results.  Do Not concat strings to make SQL;also you are leaking resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can You Try

```
Dim i As Integer = 9
While dr.Read()

If i < 15

DirectCast(Me.Controls("Label" & i), Label).Text = dr("Vencedor")

Else

End If

i = i + 1

End While
```

Comment: Really gratefull for your answer. But I still get this error http://imgur.com/a/PcZFb

Comment: Edited The Code Can You Please Try Again